# What do two opposing arrows mean in a network flow context

Tags: notation, network-flow

I came across a question with notation like this:

> $G$ does not contain any subgraph of the form $v^→_← w$.

I think this means that there is no way to push flow from v to w. Given this is a bipartite graph (because network flow), aren't these nodes useless? This leads me to believe I am misinterpreting the notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means there is no "two-cycle": a pair of arcs in opposite directions between the same pair of nodes.

Regarding "bipartite graph (because network flow)": network flow problems are also defined in graphs that aren't bipartite.

Comment: The problem specifies that it is a bipartite graph. Where did you find this? I could not find anything about this on Google. Is this uncommon notation?

Comment: I don’t have a reference, and I’m not sure I’ve ever seen this exact notation. More common would be to either draw this two-node subgraph or refer to it in-line as $v\to w\to v$.